# Errors in GNU C manual job control section?

Tags: c, shell, gnu, glibc

I'm trying to follow the GNU C [manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_27.html#SEC582) section 27 on Job Control but there seems to be some errors/typos. In the function `do_job_notification` there is a call to the function `free_job (j);` but this function is not implemented anywhere and doesn't seem to be a built-in. The variable `process *p;` is not used anywhere in the function.

Also, in the function `mark_job_as_running` the variable `Process *p;` is declared but should be lowercase as the struct was lowercase.

Could someone also give a simple main driver to demonstrate job control using the functions in the manual?

Comment: You said `free_job()` wasn't implemented, how can it have a typo? Anyhow, [`free_job` is, indeed, nowhere else to be found](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=free_job&type=). You should submit that as a bug.

Comment: The mark_job_as_running is the function with the typo. I must have accidentally changed it during my edit. How do I submit bugs? Is the manual maintained anymore?

Comment: I don't see a `mark_job_as_running`, must be on a different page.

Comment: Please check the link again. Someone edited my original link to the manual.

Comment: This section of the libc manual did not receive any significant changes for over 20 years. I encourage you to submit a few patches. Checkout the texinfo sources, generate a patch, get a bugzilla account, file a bug, and attach the patch. Your request for examples is valid but seems a bit too broad for SO.